# woocommerce checkout page endless div on payment type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i got a clean installation of wordpress and woocommerce plugin installed.
everything works, just when im on checkout page, there is endless icon upon the payment options and jquery error is triggered.

did someone meet this error? or do you know where to search to fix it. the source file is the jquery-1.9.1. min. js

the screen shows more:

http://screencast.com/t/xmGgmJrkcX

Comment: Are you facing this problem with WooCommerce 2.1 or previous version?

Comment: the newest one, 2.1 version

Comment: Does your theme has customized template for checkout page?

Comment: No, im building my own custom theme, but woocommerce has its own templates. what i do is i put a shortcode of checkout page, and woocommerce replace it with its own content. strange thing is, that now its working. it must have been some of my code, which made this strange behaviour. now its done and i dont get this kind of error no more.

Comment: That's a good news. Cheers.